# java-stream-List of Long to list of int in one line

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, long-integer

So I know I can do this with two `.stream` lines, but not sure if I can do this in just one.
Here's what I have:

```
List<Long> abcIds= abcController.findByUserIds(userIds)
      .stream()
      .map(Abc::getAbcId)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but I want abcIds to be a List of Integer since later in other function I am going to use it. I know I can write another line like this to turn List of Long to List of Integer :

```
List<Integer> abcIntIds= abcIds.stream()
           .map(Long::intValue)
           .collec‌t(Collectors.toList(‌​));
```

But is there a way to write it more elegant?

Comment: You could use two chained `map` calls, or just `.map(id -> (int)id.getAbcId())`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I tried that, but not working

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Does `getAbcId()` return `long` or `Long`? In the former case, use @OliverCharlesworth’s suggestion, in the latter case, use `.map(id -> id.getAbcId().intValue())`…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not `map` twice?

```
abcController.findByUserIds(userIds)
    .stream()
    .map(Abc::getAbcId)
    .map(Long::intValue)
    .collec‌t(Collectors.toList(‌​));
```

Comment: Or alternatvelly create a method that maps from Abc to int and use it in the map method `stream().map(YourClass::toInt).collect(toList())` where toInt looks like `Integer toInt(Abc abc) { return abc.getId().intValue(); }`